# Checking all values in the element are same

Tags: xslt

I have an xml like, values can be

```
<n1>value1</n1>
<n1>value1</n1>
<n1>value2</n1>
```

I need to check if all these values are same and if same I would need to assign it to another element. I am using XSLT v1.0.

Thanks,

Comment: I was trying with preceding-sibling, but could get it to work

Answer (score 15):

Good question, +1.

**Just use**:

```
not(/*/n1[1] != /*/n1)
```

Assuming that all `n1` elements are selected in a variable named `$v`, **this can be expressed in just 14 characters-long XPath expression**:

```
not($v[1] != $v)
```

**Explanation 1**:

By definition:

```
/*/n1[1] != /*/n1
```

is `true()` exactly if there exists a node in `/*/n1` whose string value isn't equal to the string value of `/*/n1[1]`

The logical negation of this:

```
not(/*/n1[1] != /*/n1)
```

is `true()` iff *no* node in `/*/n1` exists whose string value isn't equal to the string value of `/*/n1[1]`  --  that is, if all nodes in `/*/n1` have the same sting value.

**Explanation 2**:

This follows from a more general *double negation law* :

```
every x has property y
```

is equivalent to:

```
There is no x that doesn't have property y
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume a document of this form:

```
<root>
    <n1>value1</n1>
    <n1>value1</n1>
    <n1>value1</n1>
</root>
```

The following simple stylesheet determines whether every `n1` element has the same value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            concat('All same? ', count(/*/n1[.=/*/n1[1]])=count(/*/n1))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
All same? true
```

The key to this stylesheet is the expression:

```
count(/*/n1[.=/*/n1[1]])=count(/*/n1))
```

...which compares the count of the `n1` elements whose value equals the value of the first `n1` element to the count of all `n1` elements. These counts will be equal only when every `n1` node has the same value.

This can be made a little easier to read by first selecting all `n1` into a variable named `n`:

```
count($n[.=$n[1]])=count($n)
```

Conditionally perform some action based on the result like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="all" select="count(/*/n1[.=/*/n1[1]])=count(/*/n1)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$all">All same</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($all)">Not all same</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good answer, but there is a simpler/shorter one :)