# XSLT1 - Test if all selected nodes have a specific attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

Given the following example xml:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">right</p>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">left right</p>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">left</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">right</p>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">left right</p>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top:1px">
            <p class="bodytext">left</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to check if *ALL* the TDs of the first TR have the style attribute set to border-top.

The following expression obviously does not work:

```
<xsl:when test="tr[1]/td/@style[contains(.,'border-top')]">
 </xsl:when>
```

I'm using XSLT1, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508852/checking-all-values-in-the-element-are-same).

Basically, this is done by getting all the nodes we want to check and compare that sequence with the filtered sequence we need.

So in my case: `tr[1]/td[@style[contains(.,'border-top')]]=tr[1]/td`

Thanks Dimitre!